# conditional validation in one model but two different forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have one model but two different forms ,one form i am saving through `create` action and another one through `student_create` action.I want to validate a field in student_create action form and leave other one free.How do i do it?Any help will be appreciated

```
 class BookController < ApplicationController
     def create
      if @book.save
     redirect_to @book    #eliminated some of the code for simplicity
      end 
     end

     def student_create
     if @book.save            #eliminated some of the code for simplicity
      redirect_to @book
     end
     end
```

I have tried this but it didnt work

```
      class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
        validates_presence_of :town ,:if=>:student?

    def student?
    :action=="student_create"
    end
    end
```

Also this didnt work

```
      class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
        validates_presence_of :town ,:on=>:student_create
       end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to acomplish it what i wanted to do  by giving it  an option `:allow_nil=>true`

Answer (score 2):

In the one that should not be validated you do this:

```
@object = Model.new(params[:xyz])

respond_to do |format|
     if @object.save(:validate => false)
          #do stuff here
     else
          #do stuff here
     end
end
```

the `save(:validate => false)` will skipp the validation.

Comment: the problem is there are other fields that need to be validated in `create` though

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have two types of books.  not sure what your domain logic is but the normal flow I would do nothing.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Then for the path you want an extra validation you could do this:

```
class SpecialBook < Book
  validates :town, :presence => true
end
```

---

If this is the case you might want to consider Single Table Inheritance.

---

In another case you might want to save the student_id on the book.

Then

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_town

  private
    def validate_town
      if student_id
        self.errors.add(:town, "This book is evil, it needs a town.") if town.blank?
      end
    end
end
```